# How to add a tab to the screen of Siebel Call Center?

Tags: siebel

I am currently working with Siebel Call Center (Siebel Tools 8.1) and I'm having some trouble adding a tab to the top of the screen, where the 'Accounts', 'Contacts', etc tabs are.

I have added an item under the Page Tabs menu for the Siebel Universal Agent application, but the tab will only show up for the Siebel Administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you have not associated any responsibilities with the tab.

This can be administered under:

> Site Map > Administration - Application > Responsiblities > Tab Layout

More detail can be found here:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B40099_02/books/Secur/Secur_AccessControl40.html

Answer (score 3):

*In Tools:*

Create your Views and associate them to a Screen.

In OE go to Application, choose the desired application (e.g. Siebel Universal Agent) and expand. Choose Page Tab, create a new record with your screen.

*Compile everything.*

*In Web Client:*

Go to Administration - Application > Responsibilities, choose the responsibility and then Tab Layout, select the application (same as before), find your screen and uncheck the hide property.

*Clear the Cache.*

Log out.

Log in with the appropriate user.

Answer (score 0):

When you say tabs at the top of the Screen I'm assuming you are referring to a Siebel Screen.  You do not associate Screens to Responsibilities.  You associate Views to Responsibilities.  Because a View is a child of a Screen once a View is associated to a Responsibility the Screen will also become available.

You need to do a couple of things to get the Screen/View to be visible.

1. In the Object Explorer of Siebel tools make sure you have defined your View
2. In the Object Explorer of Siebel tools make sure you have defined your Screen
3. In the Object Explorer of Siebel tools make sure you have associated the View to the Screen
4. Take note of the View Name
5. In the Siebel Thin/Thick Client, navigate to:

> SITE MAP > Administration - Application > Responsibilities

1. Make sure that a Responsibility that you are associated with has the View (noted in step #4) associated with it
2. Click the Clear Cache button.
3. Log Out and back In

Your Screen and View should now be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this...

If you are creating the new View from scratch... you'll need to add the View as follows:

Navigate > Site Map > Administration - Application > Views

1. In the Views Applet click **NEW** to and enter view name and view description
2. Set the Local Access flag to Y
3. In the Responsibilities applet underneath, specify a Responsibility to associate with the view and set Local Access flag to Y

Then you can navigate to Navigate > Site Map > Administration - Application > Responsibilities and clear the cache